# In AngularJS, why do directive attributes need to be hyphen-separated when their scope variables are camelCased?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Html:

```
<!-- Note 'display-when' is hyphenated -->
<wait-cursor display-when="true"></wait-cursor>
```

Then in the directive:

```
scope: {
  // Note 'displayWhen' is camelCased
  show: "=displayWhen"
},
```

Why does Angular enforce this naming convention? Why not allow the `scope` setter to accept `"=display-when"` as well as `"=displayWhen"`?

Follow-up, why is all of the Html using hyphen-separated when the javascript behind it is basically all camelCase?

Might be more of a meta discussion, but looking forward to some clarification.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the duplicate. I had trouble finding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is not case sensitive but it's good practice to keep it lower case.

For completeness, attribute values are case sensitive, but tag names and attribute keys are not.